# How to send an email to subscribers?

Tags: spring, queue, jms, distributed, jms-topic

I need inputs on how I can design a simple notification system .

There is system "Z" which generates certain events (this is an external system), and there are two systems A and B (internal systems) interested in getting email notifications about those events. However, A is interested in type "error" and B is interested in type "failure" of events from Z. I am trying to design system N which will translate those events from Z and send them as an email to A and B. I am not sure how many queues/topics I require.

Please let me know if the below steps are valid/needed/or can be improved

1. System A and B subscribe to emails. If I use a queue or topic the response from N has to be published on that topic, but I want to send out an email.
2. System N is listening to queue "test" on which system Z is publishing "error" and "failure" messages.
3. System N read and translates the messages from "test" queue and send email to subscribers i.e. A and B

I am mainly not sure of step 1. How will A and B let system N know that they need email notifications?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you should deploy some kind of [MLM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_mailing_list) (i.e. mailing list manager) which both systems A and B can use to subscribe to one or more relevant lists (e.g. an "error" list and/or a "failure" list). Then system N can send emails to those lists as needed when system Z generates the corresponding events.

[Here is a list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mailing_list_software) of well-known MLM implementations.